# how can I vertically align this image within the <div> while keeping it to the right?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure what to do, I've tried using position, but it just aligns to the middle of the page, not the div.

I'm trying to align it vertically in the middle.

```css
.img1 {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  margin-right: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.img1 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid white
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="img1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in a flexbox container

```css
.img1 {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  margin-right: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.img1 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid white
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="img1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500.jpg">
</div>
```